# Typescript: Addressing state object using key gives error, because of functions in that object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, zustand

I want to address my Zustand state object using a key, but because I also keep functions within that state object - typescript throws a fit.

Typescript is concerned that, by addressing the object using a variable key, I could end up getting a function that lives in state. And that returned function can of course not be stored in the target string var.

Here's my Zustand state object, which I would like to address using key:

```
// useStateStore.tsx   
export const useStateStore = create<StateStore>((set) => ({
  // Initial state
  username: "",
  age: 0,

  // Methods to set state
  setUsername: (input) => set(() => ({ username: input })),
  setAge: (input) => set(() => ({ age: input })),
}));
```

As you can see, both setter methods live inside this state right next to the state variables themselves. This all works great, I can get a state value by addressing it with a key DIRECTLY:

```
// WorkingCode.tsx
const stateObject= useStateStore<StateStore>((state) => state);
const somevar: string = stateObject["username"];
```

However, when the key is variable, this is where typescript throws an error. It tells me that I might possibly return one of those state functions (see first code block) and those, of course, won't fit in my_username because that expects a string. This is the problem code:

```
// FailingCode.tsx
const stateObject= stores.useStateStore<StateStore>((state) => state);

const getByKey = (somekey: string) => {
  const somevar: string = stateObject[somekey];
  return somevar; 
  // typescript error
}
```

The error I get is: *No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'StateStore'.ts(7053)*

Ok, I get that: You want to make sure it's being used as a key. Let me try this:

```
// FailingCode.tsx - modified
  const stateObject= stores.useStateStore<StateStore>((state) => state);

  const getByKey = (somekey: string) => {
    const somevar: string = stateObject[somekey as keyof StateStore]; 
    return somevar;
    // typescript error
}
```

Now I get an error saying: *Type 'string | number | ((input: string) => void) | ((input: number) => void) is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)*

This is the problem line:

```
const somevar: string = stateObject[somekey as keyof StateStore];
```

And that's where I'm scratching my head. I know that typescript probably has an issue with this line possibly trying to return one of those state-kept functions being returned to *my_username*, which is a string.

I'd love to hear if someone has a good idea on how to fix this.

Comment: Why do you need `my_username` in a function named `getByKey`?

Comment: You need to tell TypeScript that the key you are using corresponds to a string type: https://tsplay.dev/wjDyvm

Comment: @vr. I've simplified code from my codebase, but to keep the example more broad I've edited my question var names a bit.

Comment: Well, again, why is your `getByKey` function only for getting keys that hold strings? I don't get why you need that to implement the function. Nevertheless, I showed how you could do it in the link above.

Comment: Try wrapping your state within the zustand combine middleware, it helps with inferring bindings.